# ECS Fargate .NET Container Calculating current memory utilization to throttle and avoid spikes

Tags: .net, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We are running Linux Docker containers of our .NET 6 application in AWS ECS Fargate - which performs some data processing on some very large objects (1-10's of GBs) streamed out of S3, chunks the objects up into piece (JSON fragments) and enqueues them to a `ConcurrentQueue`.  The application spins up several worker Tasks/threads that dequeue items from the queue and then processes them.

We ran into some out `OutOfMemory` errors initially which stemmed from the StreamReader filling the queue much faster than the items could be removed and processed by the workers. Items enqueued to the internal queue can vary wildly in size from a few KB to 10's of MBs.

We implemented a memory based throttling service to check the current memory consumption at regular intervals on the main thread to determine if the StreamReader should enter
a loop which will have it Task.Delay until the workers have dequeued enough message and total memory allocation had fallen back below a defined memory threshold.

This set up has worked  well up until we made some some code changes to tweak how messages are processed by the internal consumers, we are now hitting the same issue and reviewing the application logs versus the metrics in ECS for memory usage, it seems like there is a disconnect in how to properly calculate available memory in this type of compute environment.

Our logic for calculating the % of consumed memory is as follows:

```
private int GetCurrentPercentMemoryUtilization()
{
    long totalMemoryUsedBytes = default;
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
        totalMemoryUsedBytes += process.WorkingSet64;
    int precentSystemMemoryUsuage = (int)((totalMemoryUsedBytes / Math.Pow(1024, 3)) / (_runtimeEnvironment.MemoryGb) * 100);
    _logger.LogDebug("Total % used memory used {precentSystemMemoryUsuage}", precentSystemMemoryUsuage);
    return precentSystemMemoryUsuage;
}
```

When running/debugging the same code base locally on a Windows laptop - when evaluating total memory usage via Task Manager - the valued returned by this function matches what is reported in Task Managed on Window.

However, when running this application as a **single** container in ECS Farage, the value reported in the application logs (and used to kick on the throttle logic) is typically much lower than what we are seeing in the ECS console for Memory Utilization of the single Task.  It is typically lower and this has under certain circumstances caused memory usage to spike to 100% which in turn abruptly kill the task in Fargate. (Emphasizing that we are testing with just a single Task/container, since the metrics seem to be aggregated across all the Task in the ECS Service).

Is there something that needs to be done differently to calculate memory usage from within a container running in ECS that would explain the difference between the ECS console and what we are reporting in the application logs?

Comment: Why not just write platform-specific code which will use OS provided components to calculate this stuff, for example for Linux-based distros you can try invoking something like `free -m` and parse the output.

Comment: I tried your suggestion to utilize a wrapped call to `free` /`procps` when the app is running as a Task in ECS and I'm still getting what appears to be a mismatch between what's calculated from the app within in the container and the metrics in ECS.  The app reporting a much lower metric than what I'm seeing in ECS.  So I think this validates that the cross-platform approach I was using originally to gather this info, isn't the culprit here.

Comment: Also worth noting, I borrowed the basic implementation for the linux OS specific approach from here: https://gunnarpeipman.com/dotnet-core-system-memory/ and ran a quick benchmark, it seems going that route to get the same stats increased each of these calls from ~4ms to ~230ms.